# Size inner view in UIScrollView to the ScrollView's outer size

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint

I want to create a profile image viewer using only AutoLayout. The image viewer can contain multiple images. The user can scroll between the images horizontally using a scroll view.

This image viewer has to adapt to any size, so I can't hardcode its size.

My problem is, that the images in my scroll view have to be in the same size as the scroll view itself. But when I try to add a constraint for this, I get the following:

> Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal.

I can't attach sizes to the content view's size, because that has to have a width of multiple images. So what's the good approach for this?

Edit: I want something like this:

[image: How it should look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are adding the constraints programmatically since you get that error, anyway the trick is to link the image's size to the scrollview frame size (not content size)

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView(200)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView)]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[image1(==scrollView)][image2(==scrollView)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(image1, image2, scrollView)]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[image1(==scrollView)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(image1, scrollView)]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[image2(==scrollView)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(image2, scrollView)]];
```

This way, the images get the scrollview frame, and the contentSize is fine since it need a "continuos" list of constraints from leading to trading which you get with line 3.

Remember that before adding the constraints, the view needs to be added to it's superview

Comment: `self.view` is supposed to be the Content View (red) from the figure?

Comment: No, it's the view containing the scrollView, i used self.view as i assumed it might be a UIViewController

Comment: I see what you want to say, but this method unfortunately does not work for me. :( Here is my sample project: http://inft.ly/3nQEBWt, this produces the following output on iOS 8: http://inft.ly/mpQh4QG

Comment: Just to be clear, do you actually want to do constraints by code or Interface Builder? Because mixing both can be a bit messy... Also, do you actually need that extra contentView? You don't usually need it with scrollviews

Comment: I want to put as many constraints into Storyboard as possible, but the image constraints can not go there obviously (because images will be dynamic at the end), so I have to add some in code. That should not be a problem. I don't explicitly require the Content View, but I've read multiple sites which recommend using one.

Comment: Got it... So in this case what you need to do, is: remove the content view and the images from the storyboard, add the scrollview constraints, and ignore the first 2 lines of my code... Then create the imageViews in code, add them directly to the scrollView and then use the 3 bottom lines... This is assuming you can have a variable number of images, otherwise you could leave them in the storyboard and put the constraints there.  Let me know if it made sense